# Unable to get entities from Normalizr

Tags: react-redux, normalizr

I am new to reactjs and redux and am trying to normalize some response data using the Normalizr library. My test code is:

```
const nodeSchema = new schema.Entity('node', {}, { idAttribute: 'nodeId' });
const nodeListSchema = new schema.Array(nodeSchema);
const data = [
    {
      "nodeId": "ping.1",
      "available": false,
      "NodeApiURL": "https://www.somewhere.com",
      "NodeType": "Static"
    },
    {
      "nodeId": "testDevice1",
      "available": false,
      "NodeApiURL": "https://www.somewhere.com",
      "NodeType": "Dynamic"
    },
    {
      "nodeId": "device",
      "available": false,
      "NodeApiURL": "https://www.somewhere.com",
      "NodeType": "Static"
    },
    {
      "nodeId": "10.0.1.5:1234",
      "availableForCommunity": true,
      "NodeApiURL": "https://www.somewhere.com",
      "NodeType": "Static"
    }
  ];
  console.log("updating available nodes: ", data);
  const { entities: { nodes }, result } = normalize(data, nodeListSchema);
  console.log("updating available entities: ", nodes);
  console.log("result: ", result);
```

However,  The result comes back as expected with the list if "nodeId" values but I am not getting any entities(nodes) returned. Can anybody please tell me what it is that I have wrong.

Thanks